# JSDoc : @typedef {Object} .. How to document a method that is inside the object at @typedef

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc, eslint-plugin-jsdoc

> This is what I did so far. I want to document the method `lufthansa.book` How should I approach It ?
> Should I document It inside the Object like below? Or In the `@typedef {Object} Airline`

```
/**
 * This is a predefinition of the method that is inside the Object
 * It will be used as the type at @property {Type} for the method
 * BookMethod will be used the type of lufthansa.book
 * @typedef {Function} BookMethod 
 * @returns {void}
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} Airline 
 * @property {String} airline
 * @property {String} iataCode
 * @property {Array} bookings The array of bookings
 * @property {BookMethod} book
 */

/**
 * @name lufthansa
 * @type {Airline}
 */
const lufthansa = {
    airline: "Lufthansa",
    iataCode: "LH",
    bookings: [],
    /**
     * @type {BookMethod}
     * @param {Number} flightNum
     * @param {String} name
     */
    book(flightNum, name) {
        console.log(`
        ${name} booked a seat on ${this.airline} flight ${this.iataCode}${flightNum}
        `);
    },
};

lufthansa.book(2321, "Jean Steel");
```

> The example below didn't work. If I use this vscode initiates type check message

`Parameter 'flightNum' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage.` this is what I receive for both param if I use the approach below

```
/**
 * This is a predefinition of the method that is inside the Object
 * It will be used as the type at @property {Type} for the method
 * @typedef {Function} BookMethod 
 * @param {Number} flightNum
 * @param {String} name
 * @returns {void}
 */

/**
 * This predefinition for the Object 
 * @typedef {Object} Airline 
 * @property {String} airline
 * @property {String} iataCode
 * @property {Array} bookings The array of bookings
 * @property {BookMethod} book
 */

/**
 * @name lufthansa
 * @type {Airline}
 */
const lufthansa = {
    airline: "Lufthansa",
    iataCode: "LH",
    bookings: [],
    book(flightNum, name) {
        console.log(`
        ${name} booked a seat on ${this.airline} flight ${this.iataCode}${flightNum}
        `);
    },
};

lufthansa.book(2321, "Jean Steel");
```

Comment: I find it a bit unclear what is your problem exactly, what initiates a type check and on what? please add mode details. It seems you expect javascript to behave like typescript regarding custom types. Is it the case in VSCode? If what you are looking for is a behavious specific to VSCode, you should add its tag IMO

Comment: I want to know how to document a method. In this case the book method that inside the lufthansa Object. I used typedef to predefine the Object and it's properties. Method is a function inside an Object so how can I predefine in at typedef

Comment: Yes but what exactely are you looking for? The method `book` doesn't show on the documentation? What is the outcome of both ways you tried and added to the question? What is the link to VSCode and a type check?

Comment: it doesn't show on the documentation

Comment: I can;t add images form my country

Comment: If I ask this it's because not everybody is familiar with the tools you may use, for example, I know JSDoc but never used VSCode, so I may be able to help you or not depending on what you are looking for. You should edit the question itself to add your precisions, and use text version of code and errors rather than use images

Comment: its just that I am new to it and I am still learning even i dont know what i am asking

Comment: The correct way to document methods

Comment: how should I approach methods at @typedef

Comment: vscode is not the problem here. I provided two approaches that I tried to do. check ```@typedef {Object} Airline```.

Comment: I am not familiar with `@typedef` statements, but this is still unclear, do you mean the properties of `Airlines` don't show in your documentation for `lufthansa` at all? Or everything shows except `book`? You should be able to copy/paste the generated documentation as text to include what is your current output is and what you are looking for, in the question

Comment: well it gives only name type and description for each property of the Airline including book . But book is a function should I not have more extensive data for it. like the param and return value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several solutions. If you want to keep type definition separately from the code, you can write something like this:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Airline 
 * @property {String} airline
 * @property {String} iataCode
 * @property {Array} bookings The array of bookings
 * @property {(flightNum: number, name: string) => void} book Book a seat on a flight
 */

/**
 * @name lufthansa
 * @type {Airline}
 */
const lufthansa = {
  airline: "Lufthansa",
  iataCode: "LH",
  bookings: [],
  book(flightNum, name) {
    console.log(`
      ${name} booked a seat on ${this.airline} flight ${this.iataCode}${flightNum}
      `);
  },
};
```

or you can go backward and infer type:

```
/**
 * @name lufthansa
 */
const lufthansa = {
  airline: "Lufthansa",
  iataCode: "LH",
  /**
   * @description The array of bookings
   * @type {Array}
   */
  bookings: [],
  /**
   * @description Book a seat on a flight
   * @param {number} flightNum 
   * @param {string} name 
   */
  book(flightNum, name) {
    console.log(`
      ${name} booked a seat on ${this.airline} flight ${this.iataCode}${flightNum}
      `);
  },
};

/**
 * @typedef {typeof lufthansa} Airline
 */

lufthansa.book(1, "Jean Steel");
```